# Fail to eliminate an entry in a Python for loop

Tags: python-3.x

The following code is excerpted from a larger program; unable discard only one - always (0,4) - out of 16 possibilities: applying the same logic to all possibilities. Completely baffled. Thanks for help.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
def mystery():
    #dict generated from a 4x4 array of tkinter canvas rectangles
    geo = {1: (1, 1), 2: (1, 2), 3: (1, 3), 4: (1, 4),
           5: (2, 1), 6: (2, 2), 7: (2, 3), 8: (2, 4),
           9: (3, 1), 10: (3, 2), 11: (3, 3), 12: (3, 4),
           13: (4, 1), 14: (4, 2), 15: (4, 3), 16: (4, 4)}
    #the next two lines needed to get at the key from the values index,
    #to generate a dictionary of neighbours ... used later in the program
    geo_k = list(geo.keys())            #(list of keys)
    geo_v = list(geo.values())          #(list of values)
    #print(geo_v)
    counter = 0
    for k in geo:
        id = geo[k]
        poss_n = [(id[0],id[1]-1),(id[0],id[1]+1),  # possible neighbours
                  (id[0]-1,id[1]),(id[0]+1,id[1])]
        # print("initial ", poss_n)
        for each in poss_n:
            if each not in geo_v:
                print(each)
                counter += 1
                poss_n.remove(each)
            else: pass
        # print("final ", poss_n)
    print(counter)

mystery()
```

Answer (score 0):

While the element is in possession of the for loop you cannot remove it from the list, i'd recommend doing something along the lines of `for each in poss_n[:]` which will create a copy of the list for you to iterate over while still allowing you to remove elements from the original.

Comment: Spot on, Robert, thanks. But, as a beginner, I fail to see why the same never  happened  to any of the other 15: is it just a random quirk to be on the lookout against?